# Function returns tuple when it should not

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 and here is what I've got.

Method:

```
def get_phone(self):
    digits = filter(str.isdigit, str(self.phone))
    if re.match(r'(0|380)\d{9}', digits):
        operator = digits[-9:-7]
        digits = digits[-7:]
        return "+380 ({}) {}".format(opeself.rator, digits)
    return None
```

Now if I use this method like this:

```
dictionary = {
    'phone': User.get_phone()
}
```

the output is:

```
{'phone': '+380 (12) 1234567'}
```

But if I use it like so:

```
dictionary['phone'] = User.get_phone(),
```

The output becomes a tuple:

```
{'phone': ('+380 (12) 1234567',)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, you are just creating a tuple... That trailing `,` makes the expression become a tuple of one element... Why did you add it?

Comment: My bad... You're right =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You added a comma here:

```
dictionary['phone'] = User.get_phone(),
```

That turns it into a tuple